# Sending JSON Request to restful weservice to JAXB object

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, jaxb

My Web Service consumes "text/xml" and produces "text/xml". Am sending request parametes in request body like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sx1:user xmlns:sx1="http://www.abcd.com/service/user/dto" xmlns:sx2="http://www.abcd.com/service/common/student/dto">
<sx1:getUserType>
<sx1:username>user1</sx1:username>
<sx1:userexists>true</sx1:userexists>
<sx1:student/>
</sx1:getUserType>
</sx1:user>
```

I would like to do the same for JSON format.

With the help of jersey-jackson jar i could able to produce JSON as a response 
by using `@Consumes("text/xml")`

```
@Produces("text/xml")
```

So my question is how can i send JSON request to my service (which is a JAXB object compiled from my xsd with namespace)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send JSON File,

Please send the appropriate JSON file to the Rest Service and put the currosponding JaxB Object as a parameter to that service. REST will take autometically take care for the Marshelling and unmarshelling. Please make sure that , you need to change

@Consumes(value=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(value=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

**Make sure that JSON is proper as per the JaxB**

Comment: based on your suggestion when i send json request am getting null as response. json format { "getUserType" : { "username":"user1","userexists":true,"student":null}}

Comment: Can you update your code snippet which will make easy for me to understand ? Ideally , this should work. 

May be a problem with JAXB Marshelling/UnMarshelling

Answer (score 0):

When i use genson jar it automatically de-serialize the request and forms a java object and my resource consumes the request in given mediaType